# Error generating report in Jaspersoft Studio due to 'Error preparing statement for executing the report query'

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to generate several jasper reports in Eclipse using the Jaspersoft Studio plugin.

I have 4 parameters that will be passed in, and i am manually adding the input parameters myself.

When i run the preview it gives me Error generating report due to

```
'Error preparing statement for executing the report query: 
SELECT rcia.inquirer.`First_Name`,
 rcia.inquirer.`Middle_Name`,
 rcia.inquirer.`Last_Name`,
 rcia.inquirer.`Father_Full_Name`,
 rcia.inquirer.`Mother_Full_Name`,
 rcia.inquirer.`Sponsor_First_Name`,
 rcia.inquirer.`Sponsor_Last_Name`,
FROM rcia.inquirer
WHERE 
 rcia.inquirer.`First_Name` = '$P{FirstName}' 
 AND rcia.inquirer.`Last_Name` = '$P{LastName}''
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error. Am using a correct SELECT query? I am passing in the parameter FirstName and LastName and using them to select all of the data in the database.

[image]

Comment: Try using `$P!{}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While executing query in jasper report you can use:

1. **Prepared statement** (avoid sql injection) this is achieved by using

   ```
   $P{FirstName}
   ```

   The query in this case need's to be without qualifier **'**

   ```
   rcia.inquirer.`First_Name` = $P{FirstName}
   ```
2. **String substitution** (as @mkl comment)

   ```
   $P!{FirstName}
   ```

   The query in this case need's the qualifier (since its a simple string substitution)

   ```
   rcia.inquirer.`First_Name` = '$P!{FirstName}'
   ```

The preferred way is **Prepared statement** mainly because this will help you to avoid [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection), but also it will  help you to avoid errors if the `firstName` for example contains **'** es. *Al'Capone*, or other chars that could break your query es. \ ecc.

Comment: This did it! Wow thank you so much. It was just the unneeded quotation marks